# AudioKit: Red Mic Icon Always Appears When App In Background

Tags: avaudiosession, audiokit, avaudioengine

I’m having difficulty finding a way to get rid of the red “mic in use” icon at the top of the iPhone when my app goes to background (while not recording). Thus it gives the appearance that the app is always recording even when in the background.

Here’s how I’m initializing the mic in my AudioKitManager class:

```
// FYI: need to set to playAndRecord here otherwise crashes with “required condition is false: IsFormatSampleRateAndChannelCountValid(format)”
    do {
        try AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().setCategory(.playAndRecord, mode: .default, options: .allowBluetoothA2DP)
        try AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().setActive(true)
    } catch {
        print(error)
    }

    mic = AKMicrophone()
    let inputBooster = AKBooster(mic)
    // boost helps with pitch tracking on some iPads
    inputBooster.gain = 5

    tracker = AKFrequencyTracker(inputBooster)
    tracker.stop() // turned off until it's needed - startPitchTracking() called
    micMixer = AKMixer(tracker)

    micBooster = AKBooster(micMixer)
    micBooster.gain = 0.0
    micBooster >>> mixer

    print("Setting AudioKit.output = mixer")
    AudioKit.output = mixer

    AKSettings.playbackWhileMuted = true
    AKSettings.defaultToSpeaker = true
    AKSettings.sampleRate = 44100

    do {
        print("Attempting to start AudioKit")
        try AudioKit.start()
    } catch {
        AKLog("AudioKit did not start!")
    }
```

Things I’ve tried:

- “Stopping” and “starting” the mic when the recording vc appears/disappears. e.g. mic.stop()  -  Red icon still shows even when mic stopped.
- Setting the AVAudioSessionCatagory to and from playAndRecord and .play as recording vc appears/disappears. Really thought this would work!… but the Red Icon of Terror still stares back at me and into my soul.
- Calling: AKSettings.audioInputEnabled = false.    - Red icon still indicated mic input is enabled.
- Only initializing the mic when needed. (Tried this a while ago: seem to remember it was a total no-go)
- Dressing as David Bowie and singing “Starman” loudly into mic before app goes to background.  Probably should have been the first thing to try, but still to no avail.
- Various combinations of above

Any help much appreciated! Thx!

Kudos to AudioKit - it’s an amazing framework! :^)

AudioKit: 4.5.4 
iOS: 12.1
Xcode: 10.1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Aha. The solution is to call audioKit.stop() when the app goes to background. Then audioKit.start() before it's used again!! Goodbye red mic icon. Goodbye.

I'd overlooked this previously because I'd been experiencing a lot of issues whenever stopping and starting audio kit. However (as I mentioned in this post [Continuous Sine Wave From AKMIDISampler when AKMicrophone is Present](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53563255/continuous-sine-wave-from-akmidisampler-when-akmicrophone-is-present) ) the main problem was fixed by reloading the samples into all samplers AFTER Audio Kit is started again.

Wheew.