# AudioKit Creating Sinewave Tone When Returning from Background

Tags: swift, audiokit

I'm using AudioKit to run an AKSequencer() that plays both mp3 and wav files using AKMIDISampler().  Everything works great, except in cases when the app has entered background state for more than 30+ min, and then brought back up again for use.  It seems to then lose all of it's audio connections and plays the "missing file" sinewave tone mentioned [in other threads](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53563255/continuous-sine-wave-from-akmidisampler-when-akmicrophone-is-present).  The app can happily can enter background momentarily, user can quit, etc without the tone.  It seems to only happen when left in background for long periods of time and then brought up again.

I've tried changing the order of AudioKit.start() and file loading, but nothing seems to completely eliminate the issue.

My current workaround is simply to prevent the user's display from timing out, however that does not address many use-cases of the issue occurring.

Is there a way to handle whatever error I'm setting up that creates this tone? Here is a representative example of what I'm doing with ~40 audio files.

```
//viewController
override func viewDidLoad() {
    sequencer.setupSequencer()
  }

class SamplerWav {
  let audioWav = AKMIDISampler()
  func loadWavFile() {
     try? audioWav.loadWav("some_wav_audio_file")
  }

class SamplerMp3 {
 let audioMp3 = AKMIDISampler()
 let audioMp3_akAudioFile = try! AKAudioFile(readFileName: "some_other_audio_file.mp3")

 func loadMp3File() {
   try? audioMp3.loadAudioFile(audioMp3_akAudioFile)
  }

class Sequencer {
   let mixer = AKMixer()
   let subMix = AKMixer()
   let samplerWav = SamplerWav()
   let samplerMp3 = SamplerMp3()

   var callbackTrack: AKMusicTrack!
   let callbackInstr = AKMIDICallbackInstrument()

   func setupSequencer{
      AudioKit.output = mixer.mixer
      try! AudioKit.start()

      callbackTrack = sequencer.newTrack()
      callbackTrack?.setMIDIOutput(callbackInstr.midiIn)

      samplerWav.loadWavFile()
      samplerMp3.loadMp3File()

      samplerWav.audioWav >>> subMix
      samplerMp3.audioMp3 >>> submix

      submix >>> mixer
      }
     //Typically run from a callback track
     func playbackSomeSound(){
        try? samplerWav.audioWav.play(noteNumber: 60, velocity: 100, channel: 1)
       }
    }
```

Thanks! I'm a big fan of AudioKit.

Answer (score 0):

After some trial and error, here's a workflow that seems to address the issue for my circumstance:

-create my callback track(s) -once- from viewDidLoad

-stop AudioKit, and call .detach() on all my AKMIDISampler tracks and any routing in willResignActive

-start AudioKit (again), and reload and reroute all of the audio files/tracks from didBecomeActive